# I can't add new row , a foreign key constraint fails in Mysql

Tags: mysql

i have created two tables `User` and `Caisse` with the following code :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GGC`.`User` (
  `IdUser` INT NOT NULL,
  `LibUser` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdUser`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `GGC`.`Caisse` (
  `IdCais` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LibCais` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `RefCais` VARCHAR(50) NULL,
  `MontantCais` FLOAT NULL,
  `IdUser` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IdCais`),
  INDEX `fk_Caisse_User1_idx` (`IdUser` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Caisse_User1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`IdUser`)
    REFERENCES `GGC`.`User` (`IdUser`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

but the probleme when i try to add now row i keep getting this error message:

ERROR : #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`GGC`.`caisse`, CONSTRAINT `fk_Caisse_User1` FOREIGN KEY (`IdUser`) REFERENCES `User` (`IdUser`))

***NOTE : Although i have some data in table user***

[add new row in table Caisse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crWH4.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved , i change the type of table to InnoDB , and it work .